# kendo customised TreeList manual adding childnode unexpected result

Tags: kendo-ui, custom-controls, addition, crud, treelist

- List item

I have a page which loads a kendo TreeList by pressing a button. The data is for the moment statically defined in a variable where it stays as a basis for the Kendo TreeList datasource.

I have a datasource definition which I mostly copied from Telerik Website.
I have a treelist with a couple of requirements in terms of CRUD.

- level1 - nothing
- level2 - add new childnodes only
- level3 - edit and delete

Edit should be doubleclick on a level3 item

CRUD command buttons need to be icon-only (no text in the buttons)

I could not achieve this with the buildin CRUD controls unfortunately so I used a Template column where the buttons are placed based on their "Type" field.

Now this has worked but after some changes which I can't undo somehow the add function does not work anymore. It works but new childnode is only visible after a edit ordelete of another node. (as if the change event is not triggered during add). The Add button in the treeList calls a function addProduct where at the end I try to pushCreate directly to the datasource. However the Transport.create is never invoked. It only gets invoked after another Crud action triggers it

Can anybody see what's wrong and couldn't this all be achieve with much easier approach?

Here's the page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kendo UI Grid - CRUD operations with local data</title>

    <style>
        html {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="Scripts/kendo.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .k-grid tbody .k-button, .k-ie8 .k-grid tbody button.k-button {
            min-width: 0px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="buttons">
        <br />
        <p>
            <button name="clear" id="clear" onclick="myclear()">Clear grid</button>
            <button name="load" id="load" onclick="loadLocal()">Load from local DB</button>

        </p>
        <br />
        version 1.01<br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div id="treelist"></div>

    <script id="btn-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        # if (Code == "Product") { #
        <a id="btnupdate" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-update column hidden" title="Update product" onclick="update(this)" href="\#"><span class="k-icon k-update"></span></a>
        <a id="btndelete" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete column" title="Delete product" data-command="destroy" href="\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
        # } else if (Code == "Requirement") { #
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add column" title="Add a product to this requirement" onclick="addProduct(this)" href="\#"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span></a>
        # } #
    </script>

    <script>

        var EPDdata  // For holding the data of the TreeList


        function loadLocal() {
            EPDdata = [
                          { Id: 1, Description: "Item1", Code: "Category", parentId: null },
                          { Id: 2, Description: "Item2", Code: "Requirement", parentId: 1 },
                          { Id: 3, Description: "Item3", Code: "Product", parentId: 2 },
                          { Id: 4, Description: "Item4", Code: "Requirement", parentId: 1 },
                          { Id: 5, Description: "Item5", Code: "Product", parentId: 4 },
                          { Id: 6, Description: "Item6", Code: "Product", parentId: 4 },
                          { Id: 7, Description: "Item7", Code: "Requirement", parentId: 1 },
                          { Id: 8, Description: "Item8", Code: "Requirement", parentId: 1 },
                          { Id: 9, Description: "Item9", Code: "Product", parentId: 8 },
                          { Id: 10, Description: "Item10", Code: "Product", parentId: 8 }
            ]
            LoadTree();
        };

        function LoadTree() {
            var EPDdataNextID = EPDdata.length + 1;

            var LocaldataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: function (e) {
                        // on success
                        e.success(EPDdata);
                    },
                    create: function (e) {
                        // assign an ID to the new item
                        e.data.Id = EPDdataNextID++;
                        // save data item to the original datasource
                        EPDdata.push(e.data);
                        // on success
                        e.success(e.data);
                    },
                    update: function (e) {
                        // locate item in original datasource and update it
                        EPDdata[getIndexById(e.data.Id)] = e.data;
                        // on success
                        e.success();
                    },
                    destroy: function (e) {
                        // locate item in original datasource and remove it
                        EPDdata.splice(getIndexById(e.data.Id), 1);
                        // on success
                        e.success();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    // handle data operation error
                    alert("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                expanded: true,
                batch: false,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        expanded: true,
                        fields: {
                            Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Description: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                            Code: { type: "string" },
                            parentId: { type: "number", editable: true, nullable: true }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            $("#treelist").empty(); // only 1 treelist on the page please

            $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
                dataSource: LocaldataSource,
                pageable: false,
                edit: onEdit,
                columns: [
                    { field: "Description", title: "Description", width: "400px" },
                    { field: "Code", width: "120px" },
                    { field: "Id", title: "ID", width: "30px" },
                    { field: "parentId", title: "PID", width: "30px" },
                    { width: "35px", template: $("#btn-template").html() },
                    { command: ["create", "edit", "destroy"] }

                ],
                editable: "inline"
            });

            var treeList = $("#treelist").on("dblclick", function (e) {
                var treeList = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
                var rowindex = e.target.parentNode.rowIndex; // get rowindex
                var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                var dataItem = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList").dataItem(tr);

                if (dataItem.Code == "Product") {

                    $("#treelist").find(".edit").addClass("hidden");
                    $("#treelist").find(".edit").removeClass("edit");
                    $("#treelist").find(".delete").removeClass("hidden");
                    $("#treelist").find(".delete").removeClass("delete");

                    treeList.saveRow(); // first save all other rows
                    treeList.editRow(tr[0]);
                };
            }); // double click function
        }; // Function CreatetreeList

        function onEdit(arg) {
            var tr = $(arg.container);//.closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
            tr.find("#btndelete").addClass("hidden"); //remove btndelete from commandcolumn
            tr.find("#btndelete").addClass("delete"); //put class to select the btn later on
            tr.find("#btnupdate").removeClass("hidden"); //make btnupdate visible in commandcolumn
            tr.find("#btnupdate").addClass("edit"); //put class to select the btn later on
        };

        function update(e) { // update the edited row
            var tr = $(e).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
            var treeList = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
            treeList.saveRow();
            tr.find("#btndelete").removeClass("hidden");
            tr.find("#btndelete").removeClass("delete");
            tr.find("#btnupdate").addClass("hidden");
            tr.find("#btnupdate").removeClass("edit");
        };

        function addProduct(e) {
            var treeList = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
            var dataSource = treeList.dataSource;
            var data = dataSource.data;
            var tr = $(e).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
            var dataItem = treeList.dataItem(tr);

            dataSource.pushCreate({ Id: 15, Description: "New", Code: "Product", parentId: dataItem.Id });
            alert("Done");
        };

        function getIndexById(id) {
            var idx,
                l = EPDdata.length;

            for (var j; j < l; j++) {
                if (EPDdata[j].Id == id) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer !!!

The datasource pagesize is set to 10 and the TreeList was set to paging: false. In all my tests I started with sample data of 10 nodes. All the time I was adding an 11th and 12th record which wasn't showing up until I deleted another node...

Do these things only happen to me?